# UWP: calculate expected size of screenshot using multiple monitor setup

Tags: windows, uwp

Right, parsing the clipboard, I am trying to detect if a stored bitmap in there might be the result of a screenshot the user took.

Everything is working fine as long as the user only has one monitor. Things become a bit more involved with two or more.

I am using the routing below to grab all the displays in use. Now, since I have no idea how they are configured to hang together, I do not know how to calculate the size of the screenshot (that Windows would produce) from that information.

*I explicitly do not want to take a screenshot myself to compare. It's a privacy promise by my app.*

Any ideas?

Here is the code for the size extractor, run in the UI thread.

```
    public static async Task<Windows.Graphics.SizeInt32[]> GetMonitorSizesAsync()
    {
        Windows.Graphics.SizeInt32[] result = null;

        var selector = DisplayMonitor.GetDeviceSelector();

        var devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);

        if (devices?.Count > 0)
        {
            result = new Windows.Graphics.SizeInt32[devices.Count];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var device in devices)
            {
                var monitor = await DisplayMonitor.FromInterfaceIdAsync(device.Id);
                result[i++] = monitor.NativeResolutionInRawPixels;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Use `ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().WindowingEnvironment.GetDisplayRegions()` to get the position of each work area, and `(await DisplayMonitor.FromInterfaceIdAsync(region.DisplayMonitorDeviceId)).NativeResolutionInRawPixels` to get the monitor's resolution. What I can't find is how to get the origin of the monitor.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to work nicely. Take a quick look at my answer below, just in case there is an eventuality that I did not cover...

Answer (score 0):

Base on Raymonds comment, here is my current solution in release code...
`IN_UI_THREAD` is a convenience property to see if the code executes in the UI thread,

```
public static Windows.Foundation.Size GetDesktopSize()
{
    Int32 desktopWidth = 0;
    Int32 desktopHeight = 0;

    if (IN_UI_THREAD)
    {
        var regions = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView()?.WindowingEnvironment?.GetDisplayRegions()?.Where(r => r.IsVisible);

        if (regions?.Count() > 0)
        {
            // Get grab the most left and the most right point. 
            var MostLeft = regions.Min(r => r.WorkAreaOffset.X);
            var MostTop = regions.Min(r => r.WorkAreaOffset.Y);

            // The width is the distance between the most left and the most right point 
            desktopWidth = (int)regions.Max(r => r.WorkAreaOffset.X + r.WorkAreaSize.Width - MostLeft);
            // Same for height
            desktopHeight = (int)regions.Max(r => r.WorkAreaOffset.Y + r.WorkAreaSize.Height - MostTop);
        }
    }
    return new Windows.Foundation.Size(desktopWidth, desktopHeight);
}
```

Comment: Raymond, this is consistently 40 pixel less tall than the actual screenshot bitmap, which is precisely the height of the taskbar... hmmm. Is there a way to add that reliably to the dimensions? It could be bigger or docked at a different edge...

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to get the monitor area. You get only the work area.

Comment: Raymond, thank you for hunting this question down. I ended up using a fuzzy comparison to allow for a small difference between the screenshot size and the work area size, that the user could determine... that worked well enough. Thanks again.